# Semi advanced layout overflow issue in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Ive tried to build a widget with some requirements. To explain it simple I give an example that replicate my error:

A widget with a singleChildScrollView:

in the Scroll view there are some widgets in this example TextWidgets to make it simple:

They are ordered in this way:

SinglechildScrollView{
Column{

TextWidget1(),

Spacer(),

TextWidget2(),

Spacer(),

TextWidget3(),

Spacer(),

TextWidget4(),
...
...
}
}

I want these to behave the following way:

Condition 1: If the textWidgets together takes up less height than the screen they should be evenly spread across the screen and the last text end just at the end of the screen.

Condition 2: If the TextWidgets together takes up more height than the screen the spacers should take up zero space and the last texts should continue under the screen and be available when scrolling down.

Use this code below and try to make it work even if you add more text.

**This was the solution that i tried that did not work:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class PositioningScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PositioningScreen ({
    Key? key,
    
  }) : super(key: key);


  @override
  State<PositioningScreen > createState() => _PositioningScreenState();
}

class _PositioningScreenState extends State<PositioningScreen > {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppBar appbar = AppBar(
      title: Text('Layout issue'),
    );
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

final appbarHeight = appbar.preferredSize.height;
final statusbarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;

final totalHeight = size.height - appbarHeight - statusbarHeight;


return Scaffold(
  appBar: appbar,
  body: Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        height: totalHeight,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'Widget 1 - Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Text(
              'Widget 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Text(
              'Widget 3 - Fusce scelerisque condimentum fringilla. Donec congue ex non venenatis vehicula.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Text(
              'Widget 4 - Nulla rhoncus, sapien non euismod lobortis, velit dolor iaculis ex.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Text(
              'Widget 5 - Sed pellentesque mi nec elit pulvinar, non consectetur nisl finibus.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Text(
              'Widget 6 - Integer vitae velit non turpis rutrum pellentesque id in tellus.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Text(
              'Widget 7 - Phasellus auctor velit ut augue scelerisque, at auctor nisl pellentesque.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Text(
              'Widget 8 - sellus auctor velit ut augue scelerisque, at auctosellus auctor velit ut augue scelerisque',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


}
}
```

My solution fulfills condition 1 but when I add more text it will overflow instead of becoming scrollable and therefore fails condition 2.

I have tried this many ways but cant find the solution.

Note that this is a more complex widget in my case but i dumb down the code to find the root of the problem. Thats why there is statefullWidget even if there seems to be to no use.